# Why can't I terminate an R session? // R appears to be infinitely stuck running code

Tags: r, rstudio, terminate

I cannot restart R or run any code, because R appears to be stuck trying to run previous code.

I shut down R studio with Force Quit (because Rstudio would not quit the session itself.) I uninstalled and reinstalled R and Rstudio. But everytime I try to reopen this notebook, it wants to try to reopen where it left off. At this point I just want to restart the session and recreate my objects.

But now I can't run any code or start over, because R is apparently still trying to perform the operation. I keep getting this message:

"RStudio cannot execute 'Run Previous' because this notebook is already executing code. Interrupt R, or wait for execution to complete."

I've tried to interrupt R. I've tried to terminate the session. Nothing is working. What in the world?!?!?!

Background: I was initially trying to convert a list to characters with the toString command, but R got stuck trying to run that code.

Comment: Have you tried `Session > Terminate R` ? Have you tried restarting R using `ctrl+shift+F10`?

Comment: Check your RStudio options and project options for anything that tries to do things at startup, including General -> restore .Rdata and R Markdown -> execute setup chunk. Also check your .Rprofile for anything that might be running at startup.

Comment: Were you running a for loop per chance? Check if the "Stop" button is active in the top right of the "Console" panel of your RStudio GUI. If it is, click it and that will interrupt the code at its next possible point. I say "next possible" because R has to wait until the next step executes before stopping. For example, if it's in the middle of an individual process within your code that takes five minutes to complete, it has to wait until that is complete before stopping.

Comment: Update: This problem finally cleared but I don't know how. Think I left R running long enough that it finally tired out, or timed itself out, on trying to execute code. I was trying to go to global options to change settings. R wouldn't let me get there but suddenly the global options window opened and R executed some code I had asked it to a long time earlier. 

"Terminate R" was never working for me. I would click it but nothing would happen. I would have to do "force quit" through my mac. Also nothing with ctrl+shft+f10.

My settings are on "never" for all restore workspace options

Comment: Also wasn't running a for loop.